# How to hide JWPlayer 6 play button?

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I was using JWPlayer 5, but right now moving to JWPlayer 6.

```
<script>
    jwplayer('myElement2').setup({
        file: 'intro.mp4',
        image: 'intro.png',
        skin: 'stormtrooper',
        icons: 'false' // this doesn't work on JWPlayer 6
    });
    jwplayer('myElement2').getPlugin("display").hide();
</script>
```

On JWPlayer 5 it was `icons: 'false'` and there were no play button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to create your own skin, and leave that element out of the definition. But I think you can also do a little brute-force CSS:

```
<style>
.jwdisplayIcon {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Clicking the video frame will still start the playback.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flash you need to make a custom skin to do this.

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins

If you are using HTML5, the answer above will suffice.